# Is "bookworm" too informal?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing a introduction for myself in my website. I want to make it formal because it will be kind of "live cv". Is "bookworm" too informal? What should I say instead?

Comment: Please **include the [research](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/how-much-research-is-needed)** you've done, or consider if your question suits our [ell.se] site better. Questions that can be answered using [commonly-available references](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available) are off-topic.

Comment: Regardless of "formality", ***bookworm*** tends to have negative connotations. Perhaps you'd do better saying you're an ***avid / voracious reader*** or similar.

Comment: Define *formal* and *too informal* for your context. What is *kind of "live cv"*?

Answer (score 6):

There's nothing wrong with *bookworm*, but you could call yourself a *book-lover*, or a [*bibliophile*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bibliophile).

> **bibliophile** noun [ C ]
> ​
> A person who loves or collects books
>
> - He was also an eminent bibliophile, possessing a library of thirty thousand volumes.

Cambridge Dictionary

Comment: Too stuffy in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

I like *bookworm*, although it might be a little old-fashioned.  Here is an alternative you might like better:

***avid reader***

> avid: 1. Having or marked by keen interest and enthusiasm: an avid golfer; an avid interest in cooking.

[American Heritage](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/avid)

> Hello!  Let me introduce myself.  I am an avid reader.

But I think the best way of all of saying this is

> Hello!  Thanks for stopping by.  I love to read.

Answer (score 0):

You could opt for [*intellectual*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intellectual)

> given to study, reflection, and speculation

which is more formal, but carries roughly the same meaning.